# weird background behind navigation bar button item created from image

Tags: ios

Just trying to add a button to a navigation bar from an image.

code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *newConvoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"convos_new.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(newConvoInit:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newConvoButton;
```

result:

[image: 1]
(It should be just the dark image without the blue button in the background.)

Comment: Use `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` style not `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered `.

Comment: that makes no difference but thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely overkill for what you want. But I have a good feeling that this will make your life a whole lot easier. The following will give you just an image without any `UIBarButtonItem` attributes.

```
UIImage *menuImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarMenuButton.png"];
UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, menuImage.size.width, menuImage.size.height);
[leftButton setBackgroundImage:menuImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
```

This method implements a custom `UIButton`, which given the frame of the `UIImage` you're using, will give you nothing else but the image of your choice added to your `UINavigationBar`.

A bonus is that you don't have to worry about re-sizing anything in case the image ever changes in the future because the frame inherits from the `UIImage`.

Best of luck!